# xamarin list view not populating

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin

I am a little stuck here. I have a fragment that displays a list view. I want to load the items that make up that list view async. I do it like this:

```
 public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // do other stuff here
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            _items = await GetItems();
            _listView.Adapter = new FooAdapter(Activity, _items);
        });

        return view;
    }
```

But even though the items are getting populated the list view never is updated in the ui.  When I do the same thing with the `SwipeRefreshLayout` like so it works fine.

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    _refresher = view.FindViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(Resource.Id.refresher);
    _refresher.Refresh += async delegate {
        _items = await GetItems(true);
        _refresher.Refreshing = false;
        _listView.Adapter = new RecipeListAdapter(Activity, _items);
    };
};
```

so initially the view is empty, but when I pull down then the refresh view works and the list is populated and my list view shows up. I can't figure out why the first way doesn't work.

For reference my GetItems looks like this:

```
private async Task<List<Summary>> GetItems(bool clear = false)
{
        if (clear)
        {
            _items.Clear();
        }

       return await _service.GetItems(Token);           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example you are calling a delegate which using `await` to populate the `_items` variable before the adapter is set. But this is being bound to `_refresher.Refresh`

In your first example, you are running an `Task` asynchronously to get the data but you are returning the view before the data is retrieved. Unless something is going to refresh the data in that view how is it supposed to change?